# Proposing “training" as a new Tag

Tags: discussion

I am a just newcomer to the site. When I tried to tag my first question as “training”, it came out that such a Tag does not exist. I think training, while learning, is very much needed and therefore such a Tag could be useful. As I noticed not another way of adding such a Tag, I propose for it with this question.

Comment: *Training* in my opinion is a learning triggered by somebody else (the instructor). What you seem to mean is intensly exercising some knowledge, to know it by heart. While this is another valid meaning of training, it is also a special kind of learning and I'm somewhat sceptical, whether many questions would be applicable to that tag.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to specify what kind of questions you suggest to use that tag for?

Comment: I did edit but I cannot see my writing anywhere. Nevertheless, allow me to say that learning is one thing but, “practicing” or “training” yourself alone is a valuable supplement to the goal of learning another language. I read, after my proposal, that a Tag with name “practice” already exists. I think this could fill the need I tried to express.

Answer (score 6):

With [150 reputation points](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) you will be able to create tags for this site. This restriction prove to be useful in the past to avoid too many tags which would clutter the tag list and reduces their usability.

Tags are meant for classifying questions according to content to make them easier to find by searches and, probably more imortantly, to allow a tag subscription for people having a special interest.

Any new tag also needs a new question where it is used for the first time. Tags may also be synonymized for similar tags.

In the case of "training" please note that we already synonymized a similar tag [practice](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) to the tag [learning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), which may also be used for questions on *training*.

Comment: Indeed, “practice” can be equally well cover my proposal, without the need for one more tag. Simply, I missed that tag when looking for a similar. Would that be more helpful when all tags were also available in a simple column, just the names alphabetically, without any further information in that column? Anyhow, I feel my proposal very well covered by the information and thoughts given. THKS to all of you.

Comment: @giorgos questions with the tag "practice" will only be displayed as "learning" (= tag synonym master), with all the limitations a lean tag system has. If you feel we do need your tag anyway then just write an own answer here explaining why. Then, after enough people agreed we can add the tag anytime.

Answer (score -1):

Many sites have exercises here and exercises there, but they miss a very important section that offers practicing in all the chapters simultaneously. This section could be one where I would be asked to translate any random sentence and have the chance to compare my translation with the one offered by the site. It is like practicing while speaking alone. Refining your knowledge and capacities without the load of being misunderstood or being a load to others. Not everybody is social and speaking  a foreign language adds hesitation in the beginning. Therefore, I consider any help to practice alone very needed. I had already a good specific advice and I am thankful. Considering, now, the importance of refining one’s speaking capacities, I insist to believe that a stand alone tag either as “practice” or as “training” would be useful.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are suggesting, but this is a question-and-answer site. It is not suited to host exercises and similar. At best we can answer questions about *how* to train, learn, practice, etc.

Comment: I think you are right.